# Mobile hotspot without cell service?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I will be at a solar eclipse festival where there is no cell service (it's waaaaay out in the boonies). I would like to distribute a viewing guide (PDF) for attendees to view on their mobile devices.

What would be the best way to do this? Can it even be done? Can I create a mobile hotspot from my Android or Windows device even though there is no cell service? If so, can I create a simple page to allow them to download the document? How would I do that?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but yes, it is certainly possible to just make your phone provide a WiFi access point. A web server, however (and maybe DNS), I don't know.

Comment: File transfers using Bluetooth would work.

Comment: Not sure bluetooth would be a good solution as there may be many, many people who want to get the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create mobile hotspot without cell service, at least in stock Android. The easiest way to mass share a file I think of is by hosting an FTP server. You can find apps for that in Play Store. I grabbed [WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver) from the first ones in Play Store, which worked well. Here's what you need to do:

1. Start mobile hotspot and keep the security to None so that others could connect to hotspot freely.
2. Launch that app, go to its Settings:

   - tick **Anonymous access** -- so that others can access the server freely
   - select **Root folder** and select a directory where your pdf file(s) would be kept. Ideally, you should create a dedicated directory (through a file manager app) for it so that others would automatically be able to view only that directory.
   - tick **Read only** -- you don't want others to modify contents in your storage
3. On the app's home page, select **Start**.

   You would get something like this:

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]
4. Ask people to enter the URL in their browser. That's it.

Comment: +1 This gotta be the simplest effective way of doing it